# React routes not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a route that is not rendering. This is may be a noob questions, but I tried everything. Using the latest version of React, react-route-dom, and es6.

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Controller from './Controller'
import Floor from './Floor'


const App = () => {

return (
    <div>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/floor" component={Floor}/>
            <Route path="/controller" component={Controller}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    </div>
    )

}

export default App
```

My Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class Floor extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Floor</div>
        );
    }
}
```

My inspector:

[React inspector](http://rudes.de/images/1pic.png)

[Element inspector](http://rudes.de/images/2pic.png)

Comment: Which url did you open in your browser when nothing did render?

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need `Switch` in React Router 6.  It should be:

```javascript
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" component={<Home />} />
    <Route exact path="/Register" element={<Register />} />
    <Route exact path="/Login" component={<Login />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
</Routes>
```

no longer:

```javascript
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={<Home />} />
    <Route exact path="/Register" element={<Register />} />
    <Route exact path="/Login" component={<Login />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
</Switch>
```

Also, it's written like this now:

```javascript
<Route exact path="/Register" element={<Register />} />
```

not like this:

```javascript
<Route path="/floor" component={Floor} />
```

Comment: May you format your answer a bit clearer? Perhaps commenting out the code that is no longer needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Which URL you try on your browser? and also have you make sure the location of the `controller` and `floor` component?

For me, I access `http://localhost:3000/controller` and working fine.